# Lofting: can I copy a Shape-Keyed mesh for each frame of its animation?

Tags: modeling, animation, shape-keys

- I have made a simple profile mesh (an edge loop) which I've animated along a path
  using 'Follow Path'.
- It has a number of Shape Keys, and as it moves along the path,
  it changes shape.
- I would like to capture a copy of the full state of the mesh, in place, at each
  frame of its animation.

This would be, if you like, a sort of 'physical onion skinning'. Dupliframes capture the *transformations* of the mesh at each frame, including tilts and scales derived from the path,  varying those along the path, so come very close. But they don't capture the Shape Keys. If I alter the shape, it changes in *all* the duplicates,irrespective of keyed frames.

I'm attempting this in the hope of modeling with the resulting copies: creating a mechanism for lofting between varying profiles along a curve with a reasonable degree of accuracy, and ease of workflow.. so if there's an alternative route to that, please comment.

Comment: Think I have something similar  re [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121583/how-can-i-create-a-wallmesh-from-2-profiles-and-a-path-that-connects-them)  A follow path constraint gives an easy way to put shape at either end, and fill in the "ribs".  Be simple enough to convert from offsets to frames .Could you provide a small sample file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Bmesh script**

Select the profile mesh, run script. Creates a copy for each frame from scene frame start to scene frame end.

[image]
*A simple edge loop animated with follow path constraint, scale, and a mix of two shape keys.  `BMesh.from_object` gives a mesh snapshot at that frame (Apologies for low quality gif)*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from math import radians, degrees
context = bpy.context

dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
f = scene.frame_start
step = 1
while f <= scene.frame_end:
    scene.frame_set(f)
    bm.from_object(ob, dg)
    rme = bpy.data.meshes.new("Rib")
    bm.to_mesh(rme)

    copy = bpy.data.objects.new("Rib", rme)
    copy.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
    scene.objects.link(copy)
    bm.clear()  # interesting without.
    f += step
```

**Skinning the thing.**

Rather than having an object per rib, could also make one object.  Taking advantage of the order each rib ring is added, can bridge these edgeloops with `bmesh.ops.bridge_loops`  Could be done on a lower level by creating faces.

[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix
from math import radians, degrees
context = bpy.context

dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
scene = context.scene
coll = context.collection
ob = context.object
mw = ob.matrix_world.copy()
me = ob.data
nverts = len(me.vertices)
nedges = len(me.edges)
bm = bmesh.new()
f = scene.frame_start
step = 1
rings = []
while f <= scene.frame_end:
    scene.frame_set(f)
    bm.from_object(ob, dg)
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, verts=bm.verts[-nverts:], matrix=ob.matrix_world)

    rings.append(bm.edges[-nedges:])
    f += step

# build from rings
next = rings.pop()
while rings:
    ring = rings.pop()  
    bmesh.ops.bridge_loops(bm, edges=ring + next)
    next = ring

rme = bpy.data.meshes.new("Rib")
bm.to_mesh(rme)
copy = bpy.data.objects.new("Rib", rme)
#copy.matrix_world = mw
coll.objects.link(copy)
```

Comment: That works very nicely ...You're ahead of me!.. I was going to explore the API and try out  my inexperienced Python  to attempt just what you've done in your edit. It would have taken me a long time.  There'll be plenty more to play with :)

Comment: @RobinBetts [Using what is prob a better fill method here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122315/15543)

Comment: just can say: impressive!!! - i wish i would understand what the code does... :(