# Bridging edge loops along a curve

Tags: extrude, bezier-curves

I have two different edge loops and am currently able to bridge them. However, I would like to be able to bridge them along a curve. I know it's possible to extrude a shape along a Bezier curve and also taper a curve, but I was wondering it it is possible to use a different "start" and "end" shape for the tube.

I found these this method but both the start and end shapes are the same, just different scales:
https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool

I did find the tool I was looking for here under Sweep to Mesh but was wondering if there is a way to do it with free tools: https://blendermarket.com/products/curves-to-mesh/docs

Thank you!

Comment: Check out @batFINGER's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122232/35559)

Comment: Thank you! I saw that but in that post it looks like they already have all of the "transitional" shapes between the beginning and end, which is what I am having trouble doing