# Extrude curve via Python script

Tags: python, extrude

I'm trying to write a small script that helps me automate the creation of walls and any other wall-like segment in Blender. I wanted to use a profile curve or mesh as a base and then extrude it by X amount, adding edge loops if necessary. I find it really hard to explain what exactly I'm looking for, so I found some pictures online:

https://us.v-cdn.net/5021068/uploads/editor/sh/qkit5a52k0dx.gif
[image]
https://static.schoolofmotion.com/dfdbbe22-cebf-41c4-898d-177e86f200ad/extrude_object_hierarchical.gif
[image]
How can I select a curve, or profile mesh, and then extrude it via Python?

Comment: Why not use the bevel property of a curve?

Comment: I can't generate the edge loops that way.

Comment: Why not. Make the Curve, make the bevel curve, set the bevel, convert to a mesh?

Comment: Here's what happens: https://i.imgur.com/o7n77Tg.png There's no way to add vertical edge loops, it just becomes a huge strip

Comment: Bevel **curve** https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/properties/geometry.html#bevel

Comment: Have used this technique https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122315/15543 for arbitrarily shaped curves.  For circles there's the spin modifier too.