# Sweep along a path through multiple cross-sections

Tags: modeling, sverchok

I'm trying to make sweep along a path through multiple cross-sections. Finally got to the point where I managed to place objects along that path in correct orientation - almost. Still have some glitch or some fault in my nodes. It does place shapes right, but sometimes shape turns around 180deg. on Z axis when changing position along curve.
[image: So there is where it is standing now]
Now question is how could I make sweep of these forms along that path.

If anyone need blender file to take a look - let me know, will try to send it. and it is on 2.81a blender and currently latest sverchok.

Comment: If not already aware, you may wish to make use of https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: all profiles would need to have the same Vertex count, or at least the last profile (looks like 4 vertices) would need to have several double vertices on each of the 4 points (or subdivided so there are vertices linear interpolating the 4). I'll show an example below, and try to closely match yours

Comment: @batFINGER has given a couple of non-Sverchok answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122232/35559) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122315/35559) which may be of interest to you

Answer (score 7):

i'll further update the answer if you upload a demo blend with those shapes. I'd like to give you a nice answer.

For now, i'll clarify what i've said in the comment, with an illustration. For predictable results I recommend making sure all profiles have the same vertex count. There are two ways to do that.

subdivide the square profile.

[image]

or, double up on the destination vertices.

[image]

notice that the locations of the vertices in this "doubled up" example will produce some undesirable twisting in the end result.

---

One simple way is to interpolate both UV (slices between profiles) - without a path or trajectory". Notice how the extrusion goes exactly through the profiles too.

[image]

In the above example you must position and rotate the profiles in such a way as to achieve minimal stretching. Sverchok's *Object In* node interprets each Curve as a list of Vertices (the vertex indices are sequential and stable from Curve objects) and we interpolate between the list of resulting profiles. Get the .blend on this [issue](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/2860)

Comment: Can you loft 'normal' to intermediate profile vertices? In practice, I think this would mean that the vertices adjacent the profiles would be parallel to those profiles.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Feel free to ask a detailed question on the issue tracker with plenty of visual aides to narrow down the core. We have Bend profile Surface and Path nodes, with documentation.

Comment: i hadn't really thought about this, but i suppose when using a Path/trajectory for the loft, it lets you supply fewer profiles to achieve a particular result. Maybe try the nodes mentioned above

Comment: I feel like I've exhausted my question quota, but maybe I'll try to illustrate the point - if it's not clear.

Comment: i prefer to receive questions that can either be answered by a solution or a new node, than to see people migrate away from sverchok :)  often this does mean that we need people to spell out their needs, and then we decide if we can accommodate effectively.